# Angular2 subject unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine

How can I unit test (jasmine) subject.next() in angular2 service?

I am using subject to pass data to its observer written in component after my http call is done.

Comment: [This article](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/testing-reactive-code/) has lots of interesting examples on unit testing for observables. It doesn't use Jasmine but you can easily translate the examples.

Comment: Could you please include your code if this is not resolved yet? Otherwise update the question with an answer and mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made spy object for next() and expected that next has been called. It solved.